# Displaying primary language on App Store connect

Tags: app-store

I have set the Primary language to Japanese but the store is displaying English. Please see the photo description and let me know how to fix it. Thanks

[image: App Information]
[image: Version information]
[image: App Store displaying]

Comment: It seems like the localization I'm setting is English so the app store shows up as English. I have adjusted it in Project > Info > Localization